# Refresh Page On Div Click

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, onclick

I have a div and inside that div I have my site logo etc...

I want that when the user clicks the site logo (my div) it will redirect him to the homepage.

How do I do it? (div onlick??)

Comment: can you please share some code so we can detail how to accomplish this?

Comment: is it refresh or redirect? either way just make your logo image inside hyperlink, <a> tag, with href to the URL of your desire

Comment: Why don't you just keep it simple, and use an `a` tag with a link to your homepage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<div onclick="window.location.href = '/';">...</div>
```

replace '/' with your URL or URI.

Comment: Yes.  Can do with "location.href = ..." as well without explicit reference to "document" object.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com';" style="cursor:pointer;">Content...</div>
```

Replace `http://www.google.com` with the relative path to your site's root. The style tag just switches the cursor to a pointer so user's know it's clickable.

Answer (score 2):

```
<img src="logo" onclick="window.location('myHomePage');">

<div onclick="window.location('myHomePage');">stuff inside the div</div>
```

you can also change the window.location for a window.refresh(); if you want to refresh the page.

Answer (score 2):

Will an anchor tag work for this (I don't know what your HTML is like, etc.). It will be more semantically correct and will not require javascript. I don't think there are any browsers that object to `DIV` elements inside `A` elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/4s87y/

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
    <div style="height: 100px; background-color: #ffcccc;">
        This is a test. Woohoo!
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

one way is to use: `onclick="function(){ location.href = 'http://www.yoursite.com'; }"`

another one is to put the `div` with site logo inside an anchor tag like `<a href="yoursite.com"><div>sitelogo</div></a>`

Comment: in an event handler attribute "javascript:" should not be used. "javascript:" is a protocol which can be used in href for example.

Comment: Thanks @Spliffster I've removed `javascript`

Answer (score 0):

If you want it for OnClick then use it like this

```
<div OnClick="window.location=http://example.com">Your Content and Logo</div>
```